# OpenImages image label ontology on Google Knowledge Graph

Tags: knowledge-graph, google-knowledge-graph

I am browsing a list of all available labels for images in OpenImages [here](https://github.com/openimages/dataset/blob/main/READMEV3.md). There are thousands of labels, like `cockroach`, `ant`, `insect`. As we can see, they are not totally unrelated, `ant` and `cockroach` "belong" to the **`insect`** label category. Clearly there is a hierarchy of sorts, some ontological relationship between various labels. The above page says that they are available on Google Knowledge Graph, but I am unable to find them. Are they readily available as a compact ontology, or is there some tool that we need to use to generate the ontology end to end for all such labels?